# Pass a variable ViewModel type as generic to a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, reflection

I have a method that works with generic:

```
public static IRestResponse<T> Get<T>(long id, string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
{
        return Execute<T>(Method.GET, null, string.Concat(apiEndPoint, "/", id));
}
```

I use this method passing a view model as generic to get the parsed result:

```
var result = RestHelper.Get<AnyViewModel>(1, "Country"));
```

But I came to a case that I have a variable entity where I get the view model from:

```
var entity = "Country"; // This comes as a parameter
var viewModels = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName.Contains("Core.ViewModel"));

if (viewModels != null)
{
    Type viewModel = viewModels.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains(entity));

    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        var result = RestHelper.Get<???>(1, entity);
    }
}
```

So I can get the view model type with reflection but I don't know what to pass to the `<???>` generic of the function.

**UPDATE**

I don't know how much this influences the reflection, but I have more overloads of the `Get` method:

```
public static IRestResponse Get(string apiEndPoint)
public static IRestResponse<T> Get<T>(string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
public static IRestResponse Get(long id, string apiEndPoint)
public static IRestResponse<T> Get<T>(long id, string apiEndPoint) where T : new()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use reflection to call the `Get<T>` method with the generic parameter, using [`MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Edit** Since there are multiple overloads, use [`GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type.GetMethods(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and narrow it down to the one you're looking for.  (I don't see an overload of [`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) that lets you specify the type arguments.)

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(RestHelper).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(method => method.Name == "Get" 
        && m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1
        && m.GetParameters().Length == 2
        // just to be certain, in case someone adds more overloads in the future ...
        && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(int)
        && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == typeof(string))
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (method == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't find an overload of RestHelper.Get<T> with int, string parameters");
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(viewModel);
genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1, entity });
```

**Edit**

To use "`List<viewModel>`", you can use `Type.MakeGenericType` to get the `List<T>`:

```
var genericType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(viewModel);
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(genericType);
```

Comment: `method` returned as `null`. Maybe because I have more overloads of `Get` method? Including a non-generic overload?

Comment: Adding `BindingFlags.Public` thrown an *Ambiguos* exception on first line. Please see my edit.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Ok, so I guess you have to use `GetMethods` and filter on the type arguments, and the method arguments.

Comment: Just one more thing. Do you know how to use a collection like: `method.MakeGenericMethod(List<viewModel>);` ? It doesn't works =/ If don't or it is too hard, no problem.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown should just be `viewModel = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(viewModel)` to get the generic type.